# Looking for alternative to sleep(30) in watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to apply sleep on page loading that works completely fine, but I want to avoid using it and looking for an alternative.

I have tried these options:

```
@browser.element(:class => 'oo-pricing').wait_until(:timeout => 30) 

Watir::Wait @browser.span(:class => 'oo-blp-price').wait_until(:timeout => 30)
```

My goal is to wait until the text in span is updated.

```
browser.goto('https://secure.bestprice.rankingsandreviews.com/nc/configurator/307715')

browser.element(:id => 's2id_select_style').click

browser.element(xpath: ".//*[@id='select2-drop']/div/input").send_keys('Convertible LT 1LT', :tab)

browser.element(id: 'edit_color').click

browser.span(text: 'Incentives').click

browser.element(text: "2017 GM Conquest Cash").parent.preceding_sibling.span.click
```

Comment: which WATIR version are you using?From WATIR 6.0 onwards you don't have to use sleep statement, it automatically waits for element to exist,visible,enabled!

Comment: @RAJ I am using watir 6.2. I am looking for checkbox value to be updated on a pop up window.

Comment: I don't know what's your problem with sleep, Can you provide me to link to work out?

Comment: I have added the working code above. After the selection the amount should be $28,159 but it should wait on the window so that value gets updated. Thats where my assertion is going wrong @RAJ

Answer (score 0):

You are using Chrome driver, Chrome driver automatically closes the browser. If you had used Firefox driver, you would not be having this problem, The solution to your problem is,

Add this code

```
require 'watir'
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_options: {detach: true})
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

And then write your code

```
browser.element(:id => 's2id_select_style').click

browser.element(xpath: ".//*[@id='select2-drop']/div/input").send_keys('Convertible LT 1LT', :tab)

browser.element(id: 'edit_color').click

browser.span(text: 'Incentives').click

browser.element(text: "2017 GM Conquest Cash").parent.preceding_sibling.span.click
browser.span(text: 'Save & Update').click #Updated
```

Now your chrome browser would not closing after the program ends.

Comment: that did not help. The pop up window gets closed as soon as the check box is checked but does not update the price. My issue is not about closing the chrome browser but the value to update.

Comment: Are you clicking the Save & Update button?

Comment: Look at my updated code(last line of code), include that code in your program it would update the value.

Answer (score 0):

Find the element that you want, for example:

```
@browser.element(:class => 'oo-pricing')
```

Call the wait_until_present method on it:

```
@browser.element(:class => 'oo-pricing').wait_until_present
```

Comment: You don't have to call wait_until_present from WATIR 6.0 because it is automatic now. It automatically waits until exists?present?enabled?